# Nuxt with Markdown, extend resulting component with custom functions

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js

I'm stuck trying to extends the generated Vue component with custom functions.

Here's what I did so far:

In nuxt.config.js:

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.md$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "content"),
    loader: 'frontmatter-markdown-loader',
    options: {
      mode: [FMMode.VUE_COMPONENT],
      vue: {
        root: 'markdown' // The class name of the root div
      }
    }
  });
```

// In my page:

```
// in asyncData({ params }) :
let post = await import(`~/content/posts/${params.slug}`);

    post.vue.component.methods = {
      custom_func () {
        return 'Processed!'
      }
    }

    return {
      post: {
        attributes: post.attributes,
        component: post.vue.component
      }
    }

// And in template :

<component :is="post.component" />
```

This should work, but I get the following errors:

```
     WARN  Cannot stringify a function data                               12:23:35
    
    
     WARN  Cannot stringify a function render                             12:23:35
    
    
     WARN  Cannot stringify a function created                            12:23:35
    
    
     WARN  Cannot stringify a function image_tag                          12:23:35
    
    
     WARN  Cannot stringify a function VueComponent
```

Ideally, I would love to have a custom component in ./components/, where I inject the generated markdown that contains call to functions (like `{{ custom_func(...) }}`), and the result would be properly displayed.

I think I'm close here (even though I don't have the custom component) but I don't know why Nuxt wants to stringify everything...

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: There are a lot of posts on Meta about adding thanks and advance thanks to posts, but [this one is probably the canonical policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). This one takes on a somewhat amused tone, but the message is straightforward - technical writing is expected here, especially from experienced site users.

Comment: Please therefore omit thanks in your future questions - it is removed by curators, and there is plenty to tidy without being given more work deliberately.